# Javascript scope issues within an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I've found a posting(https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=58640) while I was googling for a similar problem as the poster's.

He was trying to figure out the fix for the code below.

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    req[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req[i].onreadystatechange = function() {

        if(req[i].readyState == 4 && req[i].status == 200) {
            URL = url[i];
            success();
        } 

    }
    req[i].open("GET", url[i], true);
    req[i].send(null);    
}
```

The solution was

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    req[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req[i].onreadystatechange = function(index) {
              return function() {
                    if(req[index].readyState == 4 && req[index].status == 200) {
                    URL = url[index];
                    success();
                   }
        };
    }(i);
    req[i].open("GET", url[i], true);
    req[i].send(null);    
}
```

and this was because of the scoping issue with `req[i]`.

I tested the value of `i` inside `onreadystatechange` with a similar function, and it printed 2, 2, 2, instead of 0, 1, 2.

Apparently something is happening to `i` value there, but I am not sure what is happening.

Comment: Also, if anyone knows a better solution, please add it. Thanks.

Comment: This is an *Extremely* common issue for new developers to run into, but if you have no idea what is going on, it is almost impossible to even Google for.  I voted to close the question because it is a duplicate, but the link there gives an explanation of what is up.  In addition, you might find this helpful as well: http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62

Comment: You will need to test the value of `index`, not `i`!

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be simplified to

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    }, 0)
}
```

it outputs `3`, `3`, `3` instead of `0`, `1`, `2`.

The problem is that the `i` in the function is the same `i` used in the loop and, since the function is called after all iterations of the loop, it is always `3`.

You can fix it using ES6 [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    let j=i;
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(j);
    }, 0)
}
```

It works because `let` declares a block scope local variable. You can't do the same using `var` because then its scope is the current execution context.

Or you can use a wrapper function:

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    (function(j) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(j);
        }, 0)
    })(i);
}
```

or

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    (function() {
        var j = i;
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(j);
        }, 0)
    })();
}
```

But then better move it outside the loop, to avoid recreating it at each iteration:

```
function f(j) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(j);
    }, 0)
}
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    f(i);
}
```